# how to parse multiple file names and get relevant information in C# asp aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to figure out a way for the program to read all of the files from the path or zip file as input.  Than read all of the file names inside of the input folder and split it so I can get information such as what is product id and chip name. Than store the pdf file in the correct db that matches with the product id and chip name.

The product id would be KHSA1234C and chip name LK454154.

Example File name: N3405-H-KAD_K-KHSA1234C-542164143_LK454154_GFK.pdf

```
public void btnUploadAttach_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fName = this.FileUploadCFC.FileName;
    string path = @"C:\mydir\";
    string result;

    result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fName);
    Console.WriteLine("GetFileNameWithoutExtension('{0}') return '{1}'", 
                      fName, result);

    result = Path.GetFileName(path);
    Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') return '{1}'", path, result);

    string[] sSplitFileName = fName.ToUpper().Split("-".ToCharArray());

    foreach (char file in fName)
    {
        try
        {
            result = sSplitFileName[0] + "_" + sSplitFileName[1] + "-" + 
                     sSplitFileName[2] + "_" + sSplitFileName[3] + "_" +
                     sSplitFileName[4] + "_" + sSplitFileName[5] + "_" +
                     sSplitFileName[6];
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if I'm on the right track or not.
Can someone help me?  Thank you.

Comment: seems like this should work, but what is your question exactly? do you have some problems with that code? Also, consider using `Split('-');` instead of `Split("-".ToCharArray());` It's clearer and you don't need the overhead in your case

Comment: I haven't tested it yet because the path button isn't working properly yet but I wanted to see if this could actually work or not.  Next step is to figure out how it will compare the tokens from the file name to the db and update it properly.

Comment: :) good ...I see you already have 3 answers, so I believe you're in good hands ... I'll keep an eye to see if there's anything I can add later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, in order to read all files in a folder you should use Directory.GetFiles, then you will iterate through this folder's files. Then you split file name's.. here you go..

```
using System.IO;
..
..
..
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.pdf");
            string result;
            foreach (var file in filePaths)
            {
                result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                Console.WriteLine("GetFileNameWithoutExtension('{0}') return '{1}'",
                 file, result);

                var sSplitFileName = file.ToUpper().Split('-');
                var i = 0;
                foreach (var item in sSplitFileName)
                {
                    if (i == 3)
                        //it is product id
                    if (i == 7)
                        //it is chip name

                   i++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a affirmative statement: You are on the right track - but not there yet :-)

First you need to read the files from your path, you don't do this currently.

`Directory.GetFiles()` may be the thing to search for. This will return a list of filenames as `string[]` array.

The you need to iterate over the files and apply the splitting, which looks ok to me in your code. 
When you have the parts of your file, you want to decide on the database to use. It may be wise to split the filename your own filename class, that exposes properties for each part of the filename, but this is not required.

Next you need to get the db programming right, there are numerous examples on how to do this. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files all follow the same pattern you can probably just split on all of the deliminator characters '-' and '_'.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\mydir\", "*.pdf");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            var tokens = fileName.Split('-', '_');
            for(int i=0;i<tokens.Length;i++)
            {
                string token = tokens[i];
                Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", i, token);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the files use '-', '_' to split up the information which makes it little easier to split it.  :)